# github php-login project : session terminates randomly

Tags: php, authentication, github

When using [php-login](https://github.com/panique/php-login) I had the experience to be oftnen kicked out of a session. The app then performs a login with the remeber-me coockie. Which performs well, if it isn't for the user experience: work lost etc...

Read some posts on a seemingly similar problem with CakePHP:

- [CakePHP keeps logging me out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278542/cakephp-keeps-logging-me-out)
- [CakePHP session/auth logging out intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573550/cakephp-session-auth-logging-out-intermittently?rq=1)

They are speaking about security levels to be adapted, but I have the impression the solutions are not implementable with php-login.

The issue is occurring both in chrome or IE.

The session.gc_maxlifetime is set to the original 1440 (24 min), but sometimes the session even terminates in less than 6 minutes.

Did someone encounter the same problem? 
Or knows how to solve?

---

Found the answer here

- [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

In fact, the issue is a configuration problem rather than a code problem. Changed the session.cookie_lifetime to be equal to the session.gc_maxlifetime (1440). No idea why these are set differently by default.

Answer (score 1):

set somewhere at start:
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 24*60*60); 
OR
got to php.ini file and change this value as You wish.

Comment: Actually 'session.gc_maxlifetime' is set to original value of 24 minutes, but session terminates sometimes even after less than 10 minutes, which indicates parhaps another issue. Anyway, I will try with this setting changed, with one reflection : having a session live during even a day of inactivity doesn't seem good practice.

Comment: I do save session in db also I encrypt cookies. I don't see the problem of keeping session alive during 24 hours.

In case of Your problem: have you set session regenerate id in your scripts?

Comment: Will evetually consider to use session regenerate id, but since it only regenerates when session id exists, this changes nothing to the problem, I think. And to give feedback to your suggestions, changed the maxlifetime, but still kicked out after less than 6 minutes. Any other possible causes?

Comment: Found the answer, you set me on the right path, thanks.